# Perform string functions on an AJAX query before returning the results from the CFC

Tags: javascript, regex, string, coldfusion, cfc

My page has the alphabet across the top 'A-Z'. When a user clicks on a letter I perform an AJAX call to a CFC that performs a query of a directory of thumbnail images based on the letter selected and returns a list of the corresponding file names.

When the list is returned to my function on the page I'm using `split()` to perform several functions on the file name to pull out certain information. For example, the file names are formatted thusly: `lastname_firstnameIMG_1234_RGB.jpg`

My goal is to extract the last name, the first name and the number in my CFC so that I can label the thumbnail image and create links to the 'real' files for downloading such as `lastname_firstnameIMG_1234_CMYK.tif` etc...

Originally, I built my AJAX function to work with the returned list using `split()` but I'm getting errors in IE. To mitigate the problem I would rather perform the string functions in my CFC and return the data ready to go.

How do I perform the string functions in the CFC before returning the data struct?

*EDIT* This set-up worked famously in Safari and FF but produced an error in IE. I tried modifying the `split()` functions and had some success but then, of course, it didn't work properly in FF. Again, my goal is to eliminate the javascript string mods and do it in the CFC.

Here's my CFC:

```
<cffunction name="List" access="remote" output="no" returntype="struct">
<cfargument name="letter" required="yes" type="string">
<cfset local = StructNew()>
<cfset local.response = StructNew()>
<cfset local.response["error"] = "">
<cfset local.response["message"] = "">
<cfset local.data = #arguments.letter# & "*.jpg">

<cfdirectory
            action="list"
            directory="#thumbsdir#"
            recurse="true"
            listinfo="name"
            name="qFile"
            filter="#local.data#"
            />
            <cfset local.response["message"] = #qFile#>
    <cfreturn local.response>
</cffunction>
```

And my AJAX function (which is wrapped in a document.ready function...):

```
$('.lastname').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#emptymessage').hide();
    $('#searching').show();
    $('#content').html("");
    var alpha = $(this).attr('id');
    $.getJSON("cfcengine.cfc?method=List&returnformat=json&queryFormat=column", 
        {letter:alpha},
        function(res, code) {
            var s = "";
            if(res.message.ROWCOUNT > 0) {
            $('#searching').hide();
            for(var i=0; i<res.message.ROWCOUNT; i++) {
            //This is all the stuff I want to get rid of...
            var theFile = res.message.DATA.Name[i]
            var theLastName = theFile.split(/_(.+)/)[0];
            var theRest = theFile.split(/_(.+)/)[1];
            var theFirstNameAll = theRest.split(/_(.+)/)[0];
            var theFirstName = theFirstNameAll.split(/(?:IMG)/)[0];
            var theImageAll = theRest.split(/_(.+)/)[1];
            var theImage = theImageAll.split(/_(.+)/)[0];
            var bw = theLastName + '_' + theFirstName + 'IMG_' + theImage + '_BW.jpg';
            var rgb = theLastName + '_' + theFirstName + 'IMG_' + theImage + '_RGB.jpg';
            //Right now I'm just returning the name to the page until debugging is complete...
                            s += '<p>' + res.message.DATA.Name[i] + '<\/p>';
            }
        } else {
            var s = "Sorry, nothing matched your search.";
        }
        $("#content").html(s);

            //End response
            }
        //End getJSON
        );

//End plist click function  
});
```

Comment: Hmm..., -1? Is this a malformed question with not enough detail? Just curious so I don't repeat offend.

Comment: Not sure why the -1, I've marked up

Comment: Yea... +1.. I'm curious why someone wanted to down-vote this...

Comment: @Richard, thanks. I wasn't sure either. The only thing I can think of is it looks like I'm trying to get someone to write my code for me. I'm not, I just wasn't sure of a good way to proceed. I've read several posts on `split()` not working properly in IE so I thought this might me relevant for CF users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JavaScript, I would do away with the regex literals and simplify the `split()`:

```
// replace with res.message.DATA.Name[i]
var theFile = 'lastname_firstnameIMG_1234_RGB.jpg';
// ['lastname', 'firstnameIMG', '1234', RGB.jpg']
var pieces = theFile.split('_');
//lastname
var theLastName = pieces[0];
//firstname
var theFirstName = pieces[1].slice(0, pieces[1].length - 3);
//1234
var theImage = pieces[2];

var bw = theLastName + '_' + theFirstName + 'IMG_' + theImage + '_BW.jpg';
var rgb = theLastName + '_' + theFirstName + 'IMG_' + theImage + '_RGB.jpg';

// lastname_firstnameIMG_1234_BW.jpg'
alert(bw);
// lastname_firstnameIMG_1234_RGB.jpg'
alert(rgb);
```

Here's how I'd do it in `<cfscript>...</cfscript>`:

```
theFile = 'lastname_firstnameIMG_1234_RGB.jpg';
// ['lastname', 'firstnameIMG', '1234', RGB.jpg']
pieces = theFile.split('_');
//lastname
theLastName = pieces[1];
//firstname
theFirstName = left(pieces[2], len(pieces[2]) - 3);
//1234
theImage = pieces[3];

bw = theLastName & '_' & theFirstName & 'IMG_' & theImage & '_BW.jpg';
rgb = theLastName & '_' & theFirstName & 'IMG_' & theImage & '_RGB.jpg';

// lastname_firstnameIMG_1234_BW.jpg'
writeOutPut(bw & "<br/>");
// lastname_firstnameIMG_1234_RGB.jpg'
writeOutPut(rgb);
```

Comment: So, would you choose the JavaScript over the `<cfscript>`? I guess I'm a little gun-shy to use the JavaScript because of it's irregularities across browsers.

Comment: @Ofeargall: I've only tried the JS in IE 9 and it worked fine. So I would choose path of least resistance and start with JS change to see how that works out. And if not, switch over to CF.

Answer (score 0):

The ColdFusion piece of this could be done in a single line of code using

```
ListFirst(list [, delimiters, includeEmptyValues ])
```

because the _ really acts as a delimiter in your case.

ListFirst and ListLast are very handy functions.